# Get the key when the value is an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, key-value

```
function getObjKey(obj, value) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(key => obj[key] === value);
}

const obj = {city1: ['Santiago','Germany'], city2: 'Chicago'};

console.log(getObjKey(obj, ['Santiago','Germany']));
```

I want to get the key of ['Santiago','Germany'] this array value as city1

```
console.log(getObjKey(obj, 'Chicago'));
```

When I try the above code, I am getting the key of 'Chicago' as city2.

Same way I want to get the key of ['Santiago','Germany'] as well. How can I do that?

Any suggestions?

Thanks for the response.

Now my Object looks like

```
const obj = {city1: ['Santiago','Germany'], city2: 'Chicago', level1: 
{level2 : [{level3:chennai},{level4:madurai}]};
```

when I pass

```
[{level3:chennai},{level4:madurai}]
```

as an argument, I need to get its key level2 . I wasn't able to find that. Any suggestions for this.

Comment: you cannot check arrays are equal using `===` you need to see if every element in value is in obj[key] if its an array using `every`

Answer (score 1):

### Idea:

You need to check whether `obj[key]` is an `Array` or not if Array then use [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every?retiredLocale=de) to check it matches with all values and if it's not just check `obj[key]===value`

**Checking two arrays equal or not by `every()` leads to a common bug** like `['A', 'B'] !same ['A', 'B', 'C']` but if we use `every()` for `['A', 'B']` it returns `true` although these two arrays are not the same. so we need to check the lengths beforehand.

```js
const getObjKey = (obj, value) => {

  return Object.keys(obj).find(key => {
    const currVal = obj[key];

    return Array.isArray(currVal) && Array.isArray(value) && currVal.length === value.length ? value.every(val => currVal.includes(val)) : currVal === value
  });
}

const obj = {
  city1: ['Santiago', 'Germany'],
  city2: 'Chicago',
  city3: 'Berlin'
};

console.log(getObjKey(obj, ['Santiago', 'Germany']));
console.log(getObjKey(obj, 'Chicago'));
console.log(getObjKey(obj, ['Santiago', 'Germany', 'Erlangen']));
console.log(getObjKey(obj, ['Berlin']));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Object.entries()`, 
check if the value is an array or not and Check if the value exists like so:

```js
function getObjKey(obj, value) {
  return Object.entries(obj).find(([k, v]) => {
    if(Array.isArray(value)) {
       return value.every(item => v.includes(item));
    } 
    
    return v === value;
  })?.[0];
}

const obj = {city1: ['Santiago','Germany'], city2: 'Chicago'};

console.log(getObjKey(obj, ['Santiago','Germany']));
console.log(getObjKey(obj, 'Chicago'));
```

Comment: This will fail when `console.log(getObjKey(obj, ['Santiago','Germany', 'New york']));` so we need to check the length as well.

Comment: you want to check part of the values or to check if exactly each exists?

Comment: I think it makes sense to check the value of a key is equal or not, so matching the whole array makes sense.

Comment: @Asraf Yes, that way you get the exact match. 
think of a case that you have multiple keys which contains common values.
only the one which has the exact values will return the corresponding `key`

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see it `value` is an array and if it is, use `Array#every` to check if `value` is found as follows:

```js
function getObjKey(obj, value) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(
      key => Array.isArray(value) ? 
      value.every((val,i) => val === obj[key][i] || '') && 
      obj[key].every((val,i) => val === value[i] || '') :
      obj[key] === value
  ) || '';
}

const obj = {city1: ['Santiago','Germany'], city2: 'Chicago'};

console.log(getObjKey(obj, ['Santiago','Germany']));
console.log(getObjKey(obj, 'Chicago'));
console.log(getObjKey(obj,['Santiago','Germany', 'Chicago','Santiago']));
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically, You are trying to compare the same array by using comparison operator (===). They looks identical but they are two distinct people :)

For the `Arrays` or `Objects`, It isn't pointing to the SAME object, but different objects with the same values.

So by comparing, we are comparing the references but not the values. That's the reason it will always return `false`.

```js
console.log(['Santiago','Germany'] === ['Santiago','Germany']); // false
```

To compare the values, We have to do something like this **:**

```js
function getObjKey(obj, value) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] === 'object' && obj[key].length === value.length) {
      return obj[key].every(item => value.includes(item))
    }
  });
}

const obj = {city1: ['Santiago','Germany'], city2: 'Chicago'};

console.log(getObjKey(obj, ['Santiago','Germany']));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare arrays with `===` , a temporary solution can be parse the values as strings and then check if they are equal:

```
function getObjKey(obj, value) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(key => JSON.stringify(obj[key]) === JSON.stringify(value));
}
```

But as I said, this should be a temporary solution since it would be slow for larger objects and JSON.stringify do unnecessary work.

---

A second option can be having different procedures for different data strucutes, is adequate if the order in the array matters and you aren't dealing with objects inside the lists:

```
function getObjKey(obj, value) {
  return Object.keys(obj).find(key =>  {
      if (Array.isArray(obj[key])) {
          return obj[key].every((element, index) => element === value[index]);
      }
      
      return obj[key] === value;
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version probably with the least change:

```js
function getObjKey(obj, value) {
  const valueToCompare = (rawValue) => (rawValue && rawValue.constructor === Array) ? rawValue.join('-') : rawValue;    
    
  return Object.keys(obj).find(key => valueToCompare(obj[key]) === valueToCompare(value));
}

const obj = {city1: ['Santiago','Germany'], city2: 'Chicago'};

console.log(getObjKey(obj, ['Santiago','Germany']));

console.log(getObjKey(obj, 'Chicago'));
```

This conversion might be a hint to structure the data being processed before doing analysis on it and separate the code for each part for easier understanding